# How can I add functionality to COM object in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, com

I am new to COM and c# and I would like to add functionality to a COM object that is exposed by a third-party program.

Initially my intention was to inherit from the COM object class, but I found out it was not so straight forward (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864199/1388292)).

Presently, I have two interfaces (namely `IComAuto` and `ComAuto`) and an associated class (`ComAutoClass`).

To add my custom methods to `ComAuto` objects, I have created a class `ComObjectWrapper` that inherits from this interface and implements it by storing a `ComAuto` object in a private field.

```
class ComObjectWrapper : ComAuto
{
    private readonly ComAuto ComObj;

    public ComObjectWrapper() : base()
    {
        ComObj = new ComAuto();
    }

    public short method1(object param)
    {
        return ComObj.method1(param);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a feeling this is not the best way to do this as I need to redirect any call to an original method to the internal `ComAuto` object.

I tried alternatively to inherit from `ComAutoClass` directly by setting the `Embed Interop types` property to `false` in VS2015. This led some method to return values as `object` when the code I have already written expects `string`. I would therefore have to go through all the written code to add some casts to `string`. Not ideal and moreover I don't have a full understanding of what `Embed Interop types` is.

I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this or point to some useful article (what I have found so far on MSDN sounds a bit cryptic for a beginner like me).

Comment: No real happy answers here, COM uses a hyper-pure interface-based paradigm.  Using inheritance is still possible by deriving from ComAutoClass, but sure, you can no longer embed the interop types.  Having one more DLL to deploy is not the end of the world.  Technically you can embed it yourself, use a decompiler like ILSpy or Reflector and copy/paste ComAutoClass.  Rename it.  It is however absolutely crucial that the COM component is never going to change again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class ComAutoExtensions
{
    public static short Method1( this ComAuto com, object param )
    {
        return com.GetShortValue( param );
    }
}
```

Comment: It does indeed! Thanks I didn't know about that.