# I get a COM exception after adding methods to a COM Interface [The procedure number is out of range]

Tags: c#, interface, com, visual-studio-2017

I had a working C# [DOT NET 4.6.1] project which used COM interfaces. After I added two methods to an interface, I started getting the exception "The procedure number is out of range. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706D1)" . This has never happened previously, and I have always been able to change COM interfaces and classes without any issues. 
I found the following in MSDN support at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838933.aspx
"Contact the supplier of the running distributed application. There is a version control problem in the application that can only be fixed by the application supplier (procedures were added to an .IDL file without changing the version number)."
I tried changing the GUID of the interface, but then the I got a cast exception when trying to use the object , saying no such interface supported.
Is this a VS2017 issue (Compile does not update the build)or is it something else? 
Please help!
Sagar

Comment: Perhaps these articles will be helpful. [How can I add functionality to COM object in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890420/how-can-i-add-functionality-to-com-object-in-c), [C# exposing to COM - interface inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863128/c-sharp-exposing-to-com-interface-inheritance), [Interface inheritance in ComVisible classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399928/interface-inheritance-in-comvisible-classes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Kunif, Perhaps my question was not clear enough. I dont have problems with adding COM functionality as such. The problem is that after adding two methods to an interface, and then attempting to call those methods leads to the above exception

Comment: Maybe the TypeLib information is outdated, and it is old information before expansion?
Please recreate the TypeLib information again from C # dll, register it again with regasm.exe, or re-execute all steps executed with the previous C # dll.

Comment: This issue was resolved by moving a getter [Property] to the last position in the list of methods

Comment: Kunif, I tried creating the tlb file using regasm /tlb, but it did not help. The only thing that worked was moving the getter/property to the last position in the list of methods

Comment: Well, in that circumstances, it probably is a matter of binary compatibility of function definition order on vTable, or problem concerning DispID numbering. It was good that the problem was resolved.

Comment: You aren't supposed to change an interface and keep the same GUID.  That said, it happens all the time. However, the main trick is to make sure you always add the new stuff to the end.  Never in the middle, never in the beginning...always the end.  You don't want to change any saved vtable layouts a client app may have from a previous version of the program. And, you don't want to change an DISPIDs of methods--which happens if you don't specifically provide DISPIDs for IDispatch compatible interfaces.  So, always add to the end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It explains the situation. But why doesnt a clean and build work? I cleaned and built both the client and the server, but it still did not work. By the way, changing the GUID gave me a no such interface error.  By the way, I havent deployed it to production yet, and so there are changes to the interfaces

Comment: Standard DLL Hell problem.  Changing the GUID is the right thing to do, when you get E_NOINTERFACE then you have a rockhard fact that the server and the client no longer agree.   Which is why it is such a good idea to change the GUID, troubleshooting gets awfully hard if you don't.  Typically the client, it has to be recompiled with the updated type library.  Note that it is an RPC error, forgetting to update the proxy/stub produces it.