# ISearchManager2 issue with signature C#

Tags: c#, com, signature

I'm trying to load `ISearchManager2` interface on C#.

Until this moment, everything works fine with `ISearchManager`. I used the Microsoft.Search.Interop assembly to do that.
I can set Catalogs, get some results from indexer and other things.

BUT, now, I want the interface called `ISearchManager2`, So, I created:

```
[ComConversionLoss]
[ComImport]
[Guid("DBAB3F73-DB19-4A79-BFC0-A61A93886DDF")]
[InterfaceType(1)]
public interface ISearchManager2 : ISearchManager
{
    void CreateCatalog([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pszCatalog, out ISearchCatalogManager _out);
    void DeleteCatalog([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszCatalog);
}
```

Same signature and order from `searchapi.h` which is:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("DBAB3F73-DB19-4A79-BFC0-A61A93886DDF")
ISearchManager2 : public ISearchManager
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateCatalog( 
        /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string LPCWSTR pszCatalog,
        /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt ISearchCatalogManager **ppCatalogManager) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DeleteCatalog( 
        /* [string][in] */ __RPC__in_string LPCWSTR pszCatalog) = 0;
};
```

With a valid `ISearchManager` Im casting like:

```
ISearchCatalogManager _out;
Teste _test = (Teste)_searchManager;
_test.CreateCatalog(catalog, out _out);
```

No error with QueryInterface (that means the interface was found) and no exceptions (with hresults). BUT, the out it's never assigned. Debugging that, I can see the `string catalog` changing.

[[image: 1]]

This is before call `CreateCatalog`. And after:

[[image: 2]]

I'm presuming the C# it's calling with an extra argument and the second (the out value) it's the string.
I tried with `PreserveSigAttribute` and other things like:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void CreateCatalog([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [In] string pszCatalog, out ISearchCatalogManager _out);
```

Because when I decompile the interface from `ISearchManager` (from Microsoft.Search.Interop) I can see that attribute on function `GetCatalog` which have the same signature.

Someone have a ideia why this is happening?

Comment: In .NET you need to redeclare all derived COM interface (ISearchManager) members in the derived interface (ISearchManager2) declaration (even if it's looks strange if you're used to C/C++). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863128/c-sharp-exposing-to-com-interface-inheritance

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. That concept wasn't in my mind. I have to put the new keyword on every function? To supress the warning. Works with and without new. You can post as a reply and I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring inherited COM interfaces in .NET you must declare all inherited interfaces members, recursively. So for example, if you have this as the base interface:

```
[Guid("2cd90691-12e2-11dc-9fed-001143a055f9"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IBase
{
    int Blabla();
}
```

Then an `IDerived` definition would be something like this:

```
[Guid("65019f75-8da2-497c-b32c-dfa34e48ede6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDerived
{
    // IBase methods
    int Blabla();

    // IDerived methods
    ...
}
```

Or better, like this, if you want to keep inheritance hierarchy in .NET:

```
[Guid("65019f75-8da2-497c-b32c-dfa34e48ede6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    // IBase methods
    new int Blabla();

    // IDerived methods
    ...
}
```