# Registering Assembly With Dependencies for COM Interop

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, registry

Sorry in advance for all the code...

I am trying to create a Visual Studio custom tool called "CliParser", and having a hell of a hard time.  In my VS solution, I have a project called `CliParser` that depends on a project called `Danware.COM`.  Danware.COM handles the boiler plate of registering a COM class as a VS custom tool with an abstract class called `VsSingleFileGenerator` and an attribute called `VsCustomToolAttribute`.  Then, CliParser defines a class called `CliParser` that inherits `VsSingleFileGenerator` and has the `[VsCustomTool]` attribute.  Both projects have been signed, had the "Register for COM Interop" property checked, and are targeting "Any CPU".  The build is completing successfully, without any COM registration errors.

And yet, I can't find CliParser in any COM clients!  Neither Visual Studio nor MS Excel show it in their Add Reference menus.  Even when I manually run regasm.exe /tlb (32- *or* 64-bit version), it says that everything was exported/registered successfully, and yet the reference does not appear in these COM clients.  How can everything be supposedly building/registering without error, and yet the actual COM types are unavailable?  All I can figure is that I am mucking something up with this inheritance hierarchy split across assemblies.  All the relevant code is shown below.  I will be *incredibly* grateful if someone can spot something that I'm missing!

Here is `VsSingleFileGenerator`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace Danware.COM {

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("A298E59F-2B16-4E2F-A5CC-61FE4B7CA676")]
    public abstract class VsSingleFileGenerator : IVsSingleFileGenerator {

        public abstract int DefaultExtension(out string pbstrDefaultExtension);
        public abstract int Generate(string wszInputFilePath, string bstrInputFileContents, string wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, out uint pcbOutput, IVsGeneratorProgress pGenerateProgress);

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        private static void RegisterClass(Type t) {
            var ga = t.GetCustomAttribute<GuidAttribute>(true);
            var cta = t.GetCustomAttribute<VsCustomToolAttribute>(true);
            string keyName = getKeyName(cta.LanguageGuid, cta.Name);
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(keyName)) {
                key.SetValue("", cta.Description);
                key.SetValue("CLSID", $"{{{ga.Value}}}");
                key.SetValue("GeneratesDesignTimeSource", 1);
            }
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        private static void UnregisterClass(Type t) {
            var cta = t.GetCustomAttribute<VsCustomToolAttribute>(true);
            string keyName = getKeyName(cta.LanguageGuid, cta.Name);
            Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(keyName, false);
        }

        private static string getKeyName(string languageGuid, string customToolName) {
            return $"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\14.0\\Generators\\{{{languageGuid}}}\\{customToolName}\\";
        }

    }

}
```

Here is `VsCustomToolAttribute`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Danware.COM {

    public enum VsLanguage {
        CSharp,
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class VsCustomToolAttribute : Attribute {

        private IDictionary<VsLanguage, string> _langGuids = new Dictionary<VsLanguage,string>() {
            { VsLanguage.CSharp, "FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC" },
        };

        public VsCustomToolAttribute(string name) : 
            this(name, VsLanguage.CSharp, "") { }

        public VsCustomToolAttribute(string name, string description) :
            this(name, VsLanguage.CSharp, description)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
        }

        public VsCustomToolAttribute(string name, VsLanguage language, string description) {
            Name = name;
            LanguageGuid = _langGuids[language];
            Description = description;
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public string LanguageGuid { get; }

        public string Description { get; }
    }

}
```

And here is `CliParser`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Danware.COM;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace CliParser {

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("F4BA90DA-E459-4889-8E14-AF27FC7437DC")]
    [VsCustomTool("CliParser", "Generates a strongly typed class to faciliate implementating a command line interface")]
    public class CliParser : VsSingleFileGenerator {

        public override int DefaultExtension(out string pbstrDefaultExtension) {
            pbstrDefaultExtension = ".txt";
            return pbstrDefaultExtension.Length;
        }
        public override int Generate(string wszInputFilePath, string bstrInputFileContents, string wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, out uint pcbOutput, IVsGeneratorProgress pGenerateProgress) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OMG did we actually make it??");
                int length = bytes.Length;
                rgbOutputFileContents[0] = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(length);
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, rgbOutputFileContents[0], length);
                pcbOutput = (uint)length;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                pcbOutput = 0;
            }
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**: Here is the contents of the CliParser.tlb created by the VS build process:

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: CliParser.tlb

[
  uuid(6C2440B0-A869-4983-A8CA-4FF470C64F18),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("Generates a strongly typed class to faciliate implementating a command line interface"),
  custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "CliParser, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e32040c76b2825f")

]
library CliParser
{
    // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    interface _CliParser;

    [
      uuid(F4BA90DA-E459-4889-8E14-AF27FC7437DC),
      version(1.0),
      custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "CliParser.CliParser")
    ]
    coclass CliParser {
        [default] interface _CliParser;
        interface _Object;
    };

    [
      odl,
      uuid(0AEBD8C3-E835-3921-8830-CCB69042366B),
      hidden,
      dual,
      oleautomation,
      custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "CliParser.CliParser")    

    ]
    interface _CliParser : IDispatch {
    };
};
```

Comment: The [ComRegisterFunction] does not do the kind of work needed to get it to show up the dialogs you are talking about.  Not 100% if that is necessary but the docs certainly suggest it is since it specifies the CLSID.  Calling RegistrationServices.Un/RegisterTypeForComClients() ought to get the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the reply.  According to this tutorial (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained), the `[ComRegisterFunction]` is necessary to automatically register a COM component as VS custom tool, otherwise I'd have to make some custom .reg script.  Those `RegistrationServices` functions look promising, but what is the benefit of using them over the built-in "Register for COM interop" project option?

Comment: You might find the nugget of gold you are after in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399928/interface-inheritance-in-comvisible-classes-in-c-sharp I wont claim it has the answer, but they are attempting a very similar thing to you and it looks like good background to the problem.

Comment: It is not necessary, it is optional.  The MSDN docs recommend you write these keys separately from the registration done by Regasm.exe with a .reg file.  Which is the logical approach for an installer.  Not that clear to me how this Codeproject could have been useful to anybody, I'd guess most programmers used step 3 and 4 instead.

Comment: @HansPassant that question does have a lot of useful info. I'm getting the sense that COM visible classes should be non-derived wherever possible.  What I don't understand though is why my assemblies are not getting registered as is.  CliParser may not expose all of its inherited methods with my current setup, but I can't get it to expose *anything*.  Why are my COM clients not aware of CLI parser even after it supposedly registers successfully?

Comment: I just edited my question to show the contents of CliParser.tlb.  I don't know what to make of it, but maybe someone else will :P

Comment: If you open your assembly in ISDASM does it show the exported COM CLSID ?

Comment: @PhillipH  Do you mean ildasm?  I'm not super familiar with that tool, but when I run `ildasm bin\Debug\CliParser.dll` I see a line that says `.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string)` followed by what looks like a comment containing the first few characters of CliParser's GUID.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes - it looks like the DLL has got the COM CLSID in it - next thing to check is the registry - if you search for the GUID in HKLM do you see your DLL as registered as the implementation of the Guid ?

Comment: @PhillipH  I get super overwhelmed when trying to search for anything in the registry lol.  I find a default REG_SZ value equal to CliParser's GUID in HKCR\CliParser.CliParser\CLSID and HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CliParser.CliParser\CLSID.  Then, I see a key named after that GUID in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID and HKCR\CLSID

Comment: Ok - this means it has been registered as the code provider for the Type associated with that CLSID. If you follow the references provided in the registry you will eventually find a file or GAC reference to your DLL. We can assume the COM registration is working then - I think the best thing is to make your code simpler (dont use inheritence) and register it again